# How to use the keys of a message to set the type of other message property (Proto)

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am trying to use the message keys to specify the property type in another message. Is there a way to do it in Proto or I need to create a oneOf and repeat the keys ?

```
message MessageName {
  string name = 1;
  string id = 2;
}

message AnotherMessage {
  [name|id] orderBy = 1; //here is where I need to use it as a type.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the behaviour you are trying to obtain, however I am pretty sure you would gain in flexibility by using `enum`s here.
Indeed, you could create an `OrderBy` enumeration as the following:

```protobuf
enum OrderBy {
  // Unspecified OrderBy behaviour, you should default to whatever you want.
  ORDER_BY_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
  
  // Order by name.
  NAME = 1;

  // Order by ID.
  ID = 2;
}

message AnotherMessage {
  OrderBy orderBy = 1;
}
```

Your server implementation would then be responsible for understanding the `orderBy` field and responding accordingly.

---

Another possibility, which I do recommend and follow, would be to adopt the ["Sorting Order" design pattern](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/design_patterns#sorting_order) described by Google in its guide to designing APIs.